# TileWMS tiles flickering on geoserver web cache request

Tags: browser-cache, openlayers-3, geoserver

I have been looking for the solution on the API page (and google too) but setting some parameters did't bring me any further. Maybe I can get the answer here :)

Is it possible to cache the WmsTiles on the browser side so if I move the map there is no short flickering?
I use geoserver with web cache (transparent tiles) but the wms request takes few seconds to deliver all tiless from the GWC cache. So if I move the map there is constant reload alltough nothing changed.

Is there is any solution to this? Tried to set the 'cacheSize' to 2048, but didnt notice any change.

Thanks

Igor

Comment: 2048 is the default `cacheSize` so you would need to make it larger to see any difference.  You could also try using the `preload` option in the layer constructor.

Comment: tnx. not sure though if this option is depricated somehow. anyway in my case we are talking about max 50-100 tiles that are fetched from the geoserver for specific map boundary. just slightly moving the map forth and back always reloads the tiles.

Comment: Increasing to 65536 does not make even the slightest change...

Answer (score 0):

The browser will not just simply load an image from its cache. It will do the http request first, the server will answer with a [`304 - not modified`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304) (what will implicitly redirect to cache) and then the browser will display the cached version. It there's a lag between the GET and the 304 response, the browser will display nothing for that amount of time.
Also moving the map will re-render it. If there's other stuff going on that makes this re-rendering slow you'll get "lag".

The trick to get around that is probably to make the `div` that displays your map bigger than your window (or the area that is displayed) and cut off the overflow so it is already rendered when it moves into the field of view. Never tried that so I'm not sure if that will work.